# What is the difference of "go to", "go over to" and "go up to" to "X's place"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In the following sentence:

> I am going to go to my daughter's house.
>
> I am going to go over to my daughter's house.
>
> I am going to go up to my daughter's house.

I have difficulty understanding these differences (my dictionary doesn't even have the definition of *go over* that is relevant to this usage). For me all seem the same, but what is the difference between them?

Comment: FYI I came up this question from this Duolingo French course if you want a source - https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/833064

Comment: Also consider “going up to London” if South of and “going down to London” if North of...

Comment: @SolarMike, Do I have to use `down` or `up`? I name the place I go to, why should I add that `down` or `up`? My destination is understood.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the first two are mostly equivalent, although "to go over to" somewhat implies that the daughter's house is somewhere nearby (in the same town, region, etc). "To go to" is slightly more generic, and could either mean the same thing (going to her home nearby) or it could mean they are about to fly a plane to visit their daughter in another country.

"To go up to" is very similar to the first two phrases, but additionally implies one of two things:  (a) the daughter lives above them, vertically - perhaps in an apartment upstairs; or (b) the daughter lives to the North of them, geographically ("up" on the map).