# "Head to" vs. "head down to". What is the difference?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I have a sentence in a book:

> *During the summers, Noel and the children **headed down to** Boca Raton, Florida, where Elizabeth’s aunt and uncle owned a condo with a beautiful view of the Intracoastal Waterway*

Why this phrasal verb is used here? Why just `headed to` (without `down`) is not enough?

Comment: Depending on context, for most of the east coast of the US, Florida happens to be to the south which means from a map perspective you move down. So I (in DC) might say I headed down to Florida, but headed up to New York or headed west to California.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference of "go to", "go over to" and "go up to" to "X's place"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197491/what-is-the-difference-of-go-to-go-over-to-and-go-up-to-to-xs-place)

Comment: @pboss3010, Indeed. _“ELIZABETH’S EARLY YEARS were spent in Washington, D.C._. I have a question though. Do I have to use `down` or `up` or `east`, `west`? I name the place I go to, why should I add that `down`? My destination is understood.

Comment: You don’t have to specify a direction, but it’s conventional to do so, maybe to give a sense of how far away something is - I think the use of a direction implies a place is relatively far away. The other linked question has a good answer that points out “go/head *over* to” is usually used for a place nearby. You could also say “go/head *out* to” to describe a place that is relatively far away - for some reason I think this is normally used for east/west travel rather than north/south travel - e.g. “Elizabeth headed out to L.A. from Washington, D.C.”